# Question about showing $\mathbb{R}P^{3}$ is not homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^{2} \vee S^3$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

A popular exercise is to show that $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is not homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee S^3$. The standard way is using cup products. This has been asked several times in various places and the solution exists online in several places such as here:

[Show that $\mathbb{R} P^3$ is not homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R} P^2 \vee S^3$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089780/show-that-mathbbr-p3-is-not-homotopy-equivalent-to-mathbbr-p2-vee-s)

The most up-voted answer says that $H^\ast(\mathbf{RP}^2\vee S^3,\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})=\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}[y]/(y^3)\times\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}[z]/(z^2)$ with $|y|=1$ and $|z|=3$

and to get this I presume they are claiming that $H^*(X \vee Y; R) \simeq H^*(X;R) \times H^*(Y;R)$. I have seen this used in other solutions also but this relationship only holds for *reduced* cohomology, and the reduced cohomology ring should be different than the unreduced version.

> Why is it, apparently, okay to use the unreduced version?

Comment: Note that $H^n(X)\cong \tilde H^n(X)$ for $n\geq 0$ and that $X\vee Y$ is path connected if both $X$ and $Y$ are path connected.

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593340/cohomology-ring-of-a-wedge-sum

Comment: Just another comment, the point is that the cohomology ring of a wedge sum doesn't differ from the product in degrees greater than zero. If the two were isomorphic there would be a generator for the product in degree one, which is clearly false. But... you're right that as stated the answer in the link you posted is not exactly correct

Answer (score 2):

You could simply argue using Homology. 
Here are some hints :

(1) Recall that the Universal cover of $\Bbb R {\Bbb P}^3$ is $S^3$.

(2) ***Prove that the Universal cover of $\Bbb R {\Bbb P}^2 \lor  S^3$ is $S^3 \lor S^2 \lor S^3$*** .

(3) Recall that $X \simeq Y \implies$ universal cover of $X \simeq $ universal cover of $Y$

(4)***$H_2(S^3)=0$ whereas, $H_2(S^3 \lor S^2 \lor S^3)=\tilde{H_2}(S^2)= \Bbb Z$***

Cheers!

Comment: As soon as you mention universal covers you are sort of using some homotopy theory, though.