# Use cup products to show that $\mathbb R P^3$ is not homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb R P^2 \vee S^3.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

This is question 3.2.7 in Allen Hatcher, Algebraic Topology.

Here is an answer to it (I found it online):

> [image]

**My questions about this solution:**

1- I believe the reduced homology in the first line is incorrect as in the zero dimention, it should be zero, am I correct?

2- for the second line, what is the reduced cohomology of the sphere $S^3$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_2$? I also believe that the given formula is incorrect as the reduced cohomology in dimension zero should be zero, am I correct?

3- I also, do not understand why we assumed that $f^*$ is an isomorphism in the given commutative diagram, what is the intuition of building this commutative diaghram like this? could anyone explain this to me please?

4- Why we have $\alpha^3 = 0$ in case of $\mathbb R P^2 \vee S^3$?

6- In the last line in the paragraph before last, should not it be $(0,b)$ instead?

5- Why is the cohomology ring of the sphere looks like this $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}[z]/(z^2)$ and $|z|=3$, according to the following [Question about showing $\mathbb{R}P^{3}$ is not homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^{2} \vee S^3$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2918000/question-about-showing-mathbbrp3-is-not-homotopy-equivalent-to-mathbb) ?

Could someone help me answer this questions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you wedge two spaces, their cohomologies are going to add, with trivial cup product between them.  The class $\alpha^2$ is the fundamental cohomology class of $RP^2$ and the next power is zero just by dimension arguments: $\alpha^3=0$.  Therefore the same is true in the wedge of the spaces.  The argument as stated above seems too wordy.  The point is that $RP^3$ has cuplength 3 (with respect to $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients), whereas the wedge has cuplenth 2 only.

Comment: I understand that the argument is too wordy, but it will give me a relief in my mind if I knew answers to my questions and if I spot the typos in this answer. Could you please give me answers to my questions?

Comment: Questions 1 and 2:  in his formulas he means to take the range $1\leq i\leq3$; alternatively, the tilde is there by mistake (note that his calculations later use non-reduced cohomology).  Question 3: if the spaces were homotopy equivalent, there would be such a map $f$ inducing isomorphisms in cohomology such that all the diagrams are naturally commutative.  Question 4: answered in my *answer*.  Question 6: NO, $(b,0)$ is correct.  Question 5 is misformatted.

Comment: what is the cohomology of $S^3$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: 1,0,0,1,0,0,0,...

Comment: Here $b$ is a cohomology class on the left side of the wedge (not in the sphere), therefore $(b,0)$ is correct.

Comment: For the last comment, I got it.

Comment: For your comment before last, you mean $\mathbb Z_2$ in dimension 0 and 3 and zero in every other dimension?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: But this solution ignored dimension zero, so I think it is better to use reduced cohomology because $\mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2  \ncong \mathbb Z_2,$ am I correct?

Comment: you are referring to the isomorphism in the second line of the solution, right?

Comment: Since the wedge is connected, is 0-dimensional homology and cohomology are still $\mathbb Z_2$.  The reduced cohomology is of course trivial.