# $\Bbb RP^3$ is not homotopy equivalent to $\Bbb RP^2\vee S^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homology-cohomology

There's some discussion about [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1089780/668308) which is incorrect actually. But I wonder if the following argument still holds:

> We have $H^*(\Bbb RP^3;\Bbb Z/2)\simeq\Bbb Z/2[x]/(x^4)$ with $|x|=1$ and $\tilde{H}^*(\Bbb RP^2\vee S^3;\Bbb Z/2)\simeq \Bbb Z/2[y]/(y^3)\oplus\Bbb Z/2[z]/(z^2)$ with $|y| =1$ and $|z| =3$. Recall that $\tilde{H}^n\simeq H^n$ for $n\geq 1$. But if we consider the degree one elements of two rings, $x^3\neq 0$ but $y^3 = 0$ so that two rings are not isomorphic. Hence, $H^*(\Bbb RP^2\vee S^3;\Bbb Z/2)$ and $H^*(\Bbb RP^3;\Bbb Z/2)$ are not ring isomorphic. Hence they are not homotopy equivalent.

I think the argument holds since the argument only relies on elements in a graded ring of degree greater than $0$. And the only difference between the reduced and unreduced cohomology is the degree $0$ part. Is this correct? Also, is there some way to represent the reduced cohomology ring from unreduced one? I mean can I represent $\tilde{H}^*(\Bbb RP^3,\Bbb Z/2)$ in terms of $\Bbb Z/2[x]/(x^4)$?

Comment: Yes you can represent $\tilde{H}^*(\Bbb RP^3,\Bbb Z/2)$ in terms of $\Bbb Z/2[x]/(x^4)$, if we think of $\Bbb Z/2[x]/(x^4)$ as a graded ring then $\tilde{H}^*(\Bbb RP^3,\Bbb Z/2)$ is just the same graded ring (without identity) but is $0$ in degree $0$. This would then correspond to to the ring (really this is a rng, a ring without identity) $x(\Bbb Z/2[x]/(x^4))$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If the spaces would be homotopy equivalent, then their cohomology rings would be isomorphic. It is also correct that the difference between ordinary and reduced (co)homology is in degree 0. You are taking the basepoint into account, and considering the map $X\to*$ that induces you $H_*(X)\to H_*(*)$ or $H^*(*)\to H^*(X)$ with $H_n(*)\neq0\neq H^n(*)$ iff $n=0$. What this essentially does is that it kills the information coming from the path component of the chosen basepoint. For the final question, in the case you would be having a path connected space $X$ (like $X=\mathbb{R}P^3$) and wanted to look at its reduced cohomology, you'd have $H^0(X)=0$ and hence no unit for ring.